# Android Studio org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.log

Tags: java, android, macos, android-studio

When I installed Android Studio on my mac (OSX Mavericks) and created a project, I got this error:

Failed to sync Gradle project 'project name'

unable to find method 'org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.log(Lorg/slf4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V'

When I first had this problem I had gradle-1.12 installed. I then installed gradle-2.1 and still the same problem. I then installed gradle 1.1 and still the same problem.
I've been trying to fix this problem for the past week to no avail.

Comment: Could this be a Gradle's dependency issue? My guess is that slf4j library is a Gradle's dependency that cannot be resolved. Probably this is an installation issue. How did you installed Gradle?

Answer (score 0):

Look in ~/Library/Java/Extensions. I had an alias in there for slf4j-api.jar, amongst other old things.  Removed that (actually I deleted the whole ~/Library/Java directory :-) and it works fine now.